# Create ASP .Net Core Webhook receiver for ABDM call by API

Tags: asp.net-core, webhooks

I am integrate ABDM APIs in our system but unable to get response in registered webhook URL.
So please create webhook receiver in API.Net Core.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("WebhookReciever")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(string))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Reciever([FromBody] dynamic response)

        {
            try
            { 
                if (response.ToString() != null && response.ToString() != "")
                {
                    bool isSave = await _abdmRepository.AddWebhookResponse(response.ToString());
                    //_logger.LogInformation(Convert.ToString(response), "store callback api data abha address is empty");
                     ModelState.AddModelError("call by api from ABDM", "response granted");
                    _logger.LogError($"Call by API response from ABDM and response is {response.ToString()}"); 
                    return Ok(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"call by api respose from ABDM is empty");
                    return StatusCode(404, response);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("AbhaAddress", $"Something went wrong when get patient details {ex.Message}");
                _logger.LogError("Exception in Call by API response " + ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
            }
        }
```

Here I register the URL with ABDM like `https://myapplicationurl/api/ABDM/WebhookReciever`,
but not getting response here.

Comment: Have you tried [Route("api/ABDMWebhookReciever")] ?